# Spring WebFlux application running tomcat instead of Netty

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I'm running a spring boot WebFlux application, normally the application run on top of a Netty Embedded server. Instead, i'm getting a tomcat instance running, i've tried to exclude tomcat from my pom and still getting the same problem.

So i would like to fix this by running Netty instead of Tomcat.

Here is my pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` (or the Eclipse POM dependency viewer) to find out where it's getting pulled in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by Thomas, springfox doesn't support webflux.

I would recommend using the `OpenApi` implementation provided by `springDoc` instead of `SpringFox` which still provides the same UI, uses swagger 3 and also supports webflux.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.33</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Springfox version 2.9.2 does not have webflux support.

Springfox 3.0.0 that includes webflux support is available as a snapshot, but will soon be released.

You can read more about it here.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2699